# How a little extra current can affect a motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, amperage, 12v

I want to run a 12V, 19 watts DC motor. Which should use 1.5amp of current. Now, I have a 12v DC, 2 amp power supply adapter. How it will affect the motor in the long term. Will it burn the motor for this little extra current?

Comment: Thought experiment: I have a 6 W LED lamp for my 230 V supply in my house. It requires about 0.025 A to run. My house supply is fused at 63 A. Will it burn out my lamp if I plug it into my house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running at its rated speed, the motor will draw just as much current as it needs to. The supply will not attempt to force more current into it.

However, a current limited supply could make a difference on startup, and on overload.

Assuming the motor is a permanent magnet brushed DC motor, then its stall current will typically be up to an order of magnitude more than its rated current. When switched on at rest, it will attempt to draw the stall current. Connected to a car battery, your motor will be able to draw that current, and so will accelerate very rapidly.

If the motor is connected to a current limited power supply, then what happens will be determined by how the supply behaves when it's overloaded. Some power supplies will simply current limit, and your motor will accelerate slowly up to rated speed. Some power supplies will shut down and restart again after a short delay. If the delay is short enough, it might burp up to speed. If it's a long delay, it may just repeatedly kick. Some supplies can shutdown and refuse to restart until the load is removed.

If you stall or overload the motor in use (in misuse), the same will apply. Having a limited current supply rated not too much about your rated current will protect the motor somewhat from overheating.

If the supply 2 A current limitation is not determined by some protection kicking in, but by how much it can supply without getting hot, then things are a little different. On startup, your supply is likely to be able to supply more than the rated 2 A for a short while, so your motor will come up to speed fairly quickly. If you overload it though, then you're likely to cook both your motor and your supply.

Comment: Great clarification. Interested to know how it is different for brushless Dc motor?

Comment: @BhaskarMaity That gets more complicated because it depends on how the ESC has been programmed as well. Note that the normal operation of an ESC is to act as a buck converter, so when operating normally you can expect the ESC to be able to supply more output current than input current when the motor is running slowly. However, if the ESC detects that its input supply is current limited, I can think of several things it might be programmed to do.

Answer (score 2):

The motor will "take" the necessary current, no matter how much extra current your source can deliver.